# strace'ing/profiling a bash script

Tags: bash, profiling, rsync, strace

I'm currently trying to benchmark a bash script in 4 different versions. Each one does a giant `rsync` job and it usually takes a very long time to finish. There are many steps in the bash script which involves setting up and tearing down the environment to rsync to.

However, when I ran strace on the bash scripts, I get surprisingly short results, which leads me to believe that `strace` is not actually tracing the time waiting for a command like rsync(which might be spawned in a subshell and is completely not recorded by rsync), *or*, it's waking up intermittently and sleep for another amount of time of which strace is not counting. Here's a snippet:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.98   12.972555      120116       108        52 wait4
  0.01    0.000751          13        56           clone
  0.00    0.000380           1       553           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000303           2       197        85 stat
  0.00    0.000274           2       134           read
  0.00    0.000223          19        12           open
  0.00    0.000190          48         4           getdents
  0.00    0.000110           1        82         8 close
  0.00    0.000110           1       153           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000084           1        61           getegid
  0.00    0.000074           4        19           write
```

So what tools can I use that are similar to `strace`, OR, maybe I'm missing some type of recursive flag in `strace` to find out correctly where my bash script is waiting on?

I would like something along the lines of:

```
% time   command
------  --------
...      rsync
...      ls
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `strace` traces system calls invoked by an executable program, not the commands invoked by a shell script, right?

Comment: @codeforester yes, that was what I meant by my first suspicion. I have edited my question to clarify that point